# Classification with Keras, unbalanced classes

Tags: machine-learning, keras, classification

I have a binary classification problem I'm trying to tackle in Keras. To start, I was following the usual MNIST example, using softmax as the activation function in my output layer.

However, in my problem, the 2 classes are highly unbalanced (1 appears ~10 times more often than the other). And what's even more critical, they are non-symmetrical in the way they may be mistaken.

Mistaking an A for a B is way less severe than mistaking a B for an A. Just like a caveman trying to classify animals into pets and predators: mistaking a pet for a predator is no big deal, but the other way round will be lethal.

So my question is: how would I model something like this with Keras?

thanks a lot

Comment: `class_weight` and custom losses.

Answer (score 1):

A non-exhaustive list of things you could do:

1. Generate a balanced data set using data augmentations. If the data are images, you can add image augmentations in a [custom data generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) that will output balanced amounts of data from each class per batch and save the results to a new data set. If the data are tabular, you can use a library like [imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html) to perform over/under sampling.
2. As @Daniel said you can use `class_weights` during training (in the [fit method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential?hl=en#fit)) in a way that mistakes on important class are penalized more. See this tutorial: [Classification on imbalanced data](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#calculate_class_weights). The same idea can be implemented with a [custom loss function](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training#define_a_loss_function) with/without class_weights during training.